# How to add a schematic if my mobile device can't run the schematics editor?

Tags: support, schematic

I'm using a touch-screen device (a smartphone or a tablet) to access this site.

Hence, the built-in circuit lab won't work for me. What do I do to add a schematic to my question?

Comment: NB: this is a [reference](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/505816/nodal-analysis-how-the-voltage-sources-polarity-is-used-in-calculation#comment1293197_505816) Q&A! Competing answers (like: use this app, use this website, shake your phone rigorously until circuit lab works) are most welcome!

Comment: Obligatory XKCD reference: [#730 - Circuit Diagram](https://xkcd.com/730/)

Comment: Falstad’s works well for my finger but better with a pen on an iPad. http://tinyurl.com/y64foldt. Why not upgrade your skills?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I think that should become an answer!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We take any kind of schematic, as long as it's clean.

Get a piece of paper, a ruler, a pen and get drawing and draw a **clean** schematic:

- Make sure you use the right schematic symbols

  - don't use any "fancy" symbols because you feel like it
  - don't draw resistors as little round components with colors, but use
    the normal US-American or IEC symbols (e.g. resistors are either
    "zick-zack lines" or "white boxes", nothing else).
- connections are vertical or horizontal. There's about two exceptions to that that also use 45° angles.

  - Exception 1: Wheatstone bridges
  - Exception 2: Bridge rectifiers
- connections are drawn with a ruler. No exceptions.
- Make sure you adhere to good schematic structure practices

  - Signal always flows from left to right.
  - Ground symbols always point down.
- It's **mandatory** components have names (e.g. R1, R2, C14, …), not just values (100 Ω, 2 kΩ, 100 nF), so that we can refer to them by name when discussing them.
- use a dot ⏺ to mark junctions between traces, and if it helps clarity, use an arch ∩ to mark a crossing that isn't a junction (i.e. where the two traces are not connected.

---

Then, take a **good** photo.

Hints for taking good photos:

- use much light from around, so that there's no shadows or bright spot

  - using the flash is usually not a good idea, since that will overexpose some of the paper, but underexpose the rest
- Take a photo that isn't at an angle, but straight.
- Make sure the whole drawing is *in focus* – being sharp is better than being blurry but larger.

  - Check that the picture is sharp!
  - Your camera won't be able to focus on the paper if you're up too close. If you zoom in and the lines aren't crisp, try moving away from the paper.
- Rotate your image so that it's upright

  - (feels a bit stupid to say that, but reality is it's often missed) a 90° or 180° rotation is not acceptable
- Crop your picture to the relevant part.
- Most importantly, really check the image is OK before uploading it. Zoom in, and scroll around in it.

All that can be done with any modern smart phone or tablet.

---

Couple of examples. Even the "this is good enough" example isn't perfect, on purpose. Neither is the way the schematic has been drawn. This all goes to show that with

[image: OK]

OK, could be brighter and slightly more evenly lit, better white balance. This works, however.

---

[image: shadow]

A shadow obscuring parts of the image. Sometimes hard to avoid when not having a lot of ambient light.

---

[image: Flashed]

Used flash: image overexposed in the center, underexposed elsewhere. Also, upside down, unsharp.

---

[image: uncropped]

Needs cropping. The relevant part only takes up a small fraction of the image area.

---

[image: rotated]

Needs to be upright.

---

[image: out of focus]

Picture above is out of focus. Camera was too close to paper.

---

[image: slightly out of focus]

Still out of focus, though not as badly, but still too close. Having more pixels of your schematic doesn't help if they're blurry!

---

[image: slanted]
[image: slanted2]

Pictures taken at an angle. A very common mistake, because one rarely looks at a piece of paper from straight above. However, one typically looks at a screen in a very straight way, so this isn't great.
Notice how due to the difference in distance, some parts are out of focus.

---

[image: overcompressed and underenjoyed]

Overcompressed; rarely happens these days, but when using image compression apps, make sure you avoid having such visible JPEG artifacts.

Comment: I have to say that all of those images are better than no image at all.

Comment: @SolarMike indeed, they are!

Comment: I will use this to suggest to posters when they don't include a diagram.

Comment: that was exactly the intention

Comment: the fact that it's a bit on the overly helpful side with regards to photography is exactly to make it useful to both: the people that don't include a schematic at all because "thick thumb-operated devices can't run the circuit lab schematic editor" and these that "here's a photo, lit by burning lard in the next room, shot at an artistically interesting angle of 117.23°, with the camera focusing on the alps, which happen to be 12,812 km away". Reading that, this describes a lot of "identify this component" photos, too.

Comment: Related: [Rules and guidelines for drawing good schematics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/28251/rules-and-guidelines-for-drawing-good-schematics)

Answer (score 2):

I once had a boss with lots of experience and a PhD but did not know how to use a computer, but he knew the power of a pencil.

Meaning: you don't need computer skills or even a schematic editor to be a great engineer.

This was filtered from @MarcusMüller 's last photo.

[image]

But you need some computer skills to make a readable photo.